# How to switch Mapbox base map layers?

Tags: mapbox, basemap

Can someone help me on how I can switch the basemap layers?

I'm using **[Mapbox layers](http://vizonomy.com/cityscan/philadelphiav2)**, but when I switch from satellite to road, the feature layer is pushed to the behind the new basemap.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when your code does not differentiate between Basemaps and Overlays.

Your feature layers should be added to the map as `overlays` and not `basemaps`.

The following example is from the [Leaflet LayersControl docs page](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html)

```
var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-key/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade';

var minimal   = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {styleId: 22677, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution}),
    midnight  = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {styleId: 999,   attribution: cloudmadeAttribution}),
    motorways = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {styleId: 46561, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(39.73, -104.99),
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [minimal, motorways, cities]
});

var baseMaps = {
    "Minimal": minimal,
    "Night View": midnight
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Motorways": motorways,
    "Cities": cities
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

At this point, the basemaps (Minimal and Night View) will always be underneath the overlays (Motorways and Cities) - no matter how many times you switch between basemaps.

Make sure your feature layers are added to the map as `overlays` and not as `basemaps`.